# Is there a better way to apply separate kernels on different parts of an image in a CNN using Keras and TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I need CNN to apply 3 different kernels on upper, middle and lower 3rd part of image by splitting it in 3 parts and then concatenate it. Suppose image is `240*240*1`. This should happen in first layer, after that remaining conv2d layers and maxpooling should come regularly like 16 filters in next conv2d, next 32, then 64 and so on. First layer should have 3 separate 3*3 kernels each for separate part of image, where kernel1 convolutes upper third, kernel2 convolutes middle and kernel3 convolutes lower 3rd part. (Below code is not showing any error but models accuracy is very low which shouldn't be happening theoretically. Can below code does it or is there better way to do it?

```
# Define the custom kernels for different parts of the image
kernel1 = np.array([[-0.5, -0.1, 0.5],
                    [-0.5, 1, 0.5],
                    [-0.5, -0.1, 0.5]])

kernel2 = np.array([[-2, 0, 2],
                    [-2, 0, 2],
                    [-2, 0, 2]])

kernel3 = np.array([[-1, -0.5, -1],
                    [-0.5, 7, -0.5],
                    [-1, -0.5, -1]])

# Define the custom kernel weights for the first layer
first_kernel_weights = [[0,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,0]]

# Define the CNN model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(1, (3, 3), input_shape=(image_height, image_width, 1), padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(first_kernel_weights)))

# Split the input shape into three parts
split_height = image_height // 3


# Convolution with kernel1 for region 1
region1 = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel1))(model.output[:, :split_height, :, :])

# Convolution with kernel2 for region 2
region2 = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel2))(model.output[:, split_height:2*split_height, :, :])

# Convolution with kernel3 for region 3
region3 = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(kernel3))(model.output[:, 2*split_height:, :, :])

# Merge the regions back into a single tensor
merged_regions = tf.concat([region1, region2, region3], axis=1)

model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(16,3, 3))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3,padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((1,1), strides=(1,1)))


model.add(Conv2D(124, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=((0, 1), (0, 1))))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))

model.add(Dense(124, activation='softmax'))

# Display the results or perform further operations with the model

print("Model summary:")
print(model.summary())
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I tried this model and it should give good results theoretically but gives 3,4% accuracy. Although when training epochs accuracy goes upto, 99 but final accuracy turns out to be very low. Need to be sure if above code block is actually doing what I want it to do that is 'three separate kernels should run on three different parts and then their results shall be combined and further processing or filters be worked on that'

Comment: please share the training history and evaluation